# Система оповещения!

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я тут писал на python телеграмм бота и у меня возникла проблема с тем что я могу сделать систему оповещений, но его нельзя будет выключить, я долго искал в интернете но так и ничего не нашел, у меня вопрос такой: "Как сделать так чтобы клиент мог отключать и включать уведомление по желанию" (я использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi)

Comment: Сохранять настройку оповещений, а включать/выключать эту настройку по комманде от юзера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай **БД**, в которой храни значения (True / False).

UserID    Value (1/0)

**True** - Если пользователь подписан на рассылку, **False**, если нет.

Я вижу, ты начинающий, по этому тебе лучше подойдёт [PickleDB](https://pythonhosted.org/pickleDB/).